# WKInterfaceTable scrollbar height

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, wkinterfacetable

How can I change the height of a `WKInterfaceTable` scrollbar? By default scrollbar height is equal to 1 row‘s height. What I am missing?

[image]

Comment: Where you able to fix this? I'm having the same issue. I also noticed that the last row gets cut off a bit. Does yours do this second issue too with cutting off the last row? I posted about it [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158255/wkinterfacetable-rendering-issues-both-the-scroll-bar-and-last-row-are-cut-off) Let me know if you've solved it! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is NO such API to achieve this currently. WatchKit is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the row hight, it's the size of the digital crown.