# WKInterfaceTable rendering issues. Both the scroll bar and last row are cut off

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, watchkit, wkinterfacetable

I'm developing a WatchKit app for the Apple Watch. I "finished" the app originally when the first beta was out back in Nov/Dec.

I recently upgraded the the final release and somethings in WatchKit changed (as to be expected). I had to fix couple lines of code here and there since they changed how the app views start up.

Anyway, after fixing the issues I noticed that my `WKInterfaceTable` displays and scrolls *almost* correctly. The last row in the table gets cut off (as indicated in the screenshot below). Also, the scrollbar is very short - shorter than it should be (also in the screenshot). Anyone else experiencing this?

### [image: Heading]

*In the screenshot, the app has about 10 rows, I just scrolled way to the bottom with a bit of an extra pull just to show the cut-off from the last row... Notice the bottom of the row  and the scrollbar at the top right.*

I've included extra screenshots that may be helpful. I researched some tutorials on `WKInterfaceTable` and they're not really doing anything different than I am in the Interface Builder. I'm lost here.

I'm not making ANY UI modifications in code. I'm just letting WatchKit handle the UI as much as possible without any intervention from me.

Thanks!

Other Screenshots:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The scrollbar is short by design, this isn't a bug. That's how it's meant to be.

Regarding the cutting off of the last row, add the table into a WKInterfaceGroup, then set the group's height to 'Size to Fit Content'. That should fix it.

Comment: I will try this when I get a chance. Has this proven successful for you?

Comment: Well I haven't tried what you're doing but yeah I've got a similar app with a table and I have enclosed it in a group just like so. Works perfectly.

Comment: This original post seems to be fixed in watchOS 6. But this solution (for pre-watchOS 6 compat) results in a non-scrolling `WKInterfaceTable` in watchOS 6 (if "fixed to screen edges" was set on the interface controller). Disable "fixed to screen edges" and it seems to work for watchOS 4-6.